# Consulta con campos Dinámicos

Tags: sql-server

Tengo dos tablas:
Tabla1
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla 2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero realizar una consuta en SQL sin SP que muestre los campos de Tabla1 pero solamente los que tengan la marca 'X' en tabla 2. También hay que considerar que la marca 'X' de tabla 2 puede puede estar en más campos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido Ronald Valdez a Stack Overflow en español, es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que esta sea bien recibida por la comunidad. Trata de agregar las estructura y ejemplos de tablas como texto y no como imagen, además agrega lo que hayas intentado hasta el momento y que dificultas has tenido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes usar INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS para acceder al nombre de las columnas de tu tabla y formar tu query de forma dinámica.

```
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = 'select '
SELECT @sql = @sql + '[' + column_name +'],'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Tabla1' 
AND COLUMN_NAME IN(SELECT Tipo FROM Tabla2 WHERE Calculo = 'x')
SET @sql = left(@sql,len(@sql)-1)
SET @sql = @sql + ' from Tabla1'
EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Código tomado de: [sql select with column name like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274594/sql-select-with-column-name-like/23704091)

Comment: Excelente respuesta, muchas gracias

Comment: Cómo sería si quiero hacer la consulta desde una tabla temporal, en lugar de tabla 1, #Tempo

Comment: Con este query obtienes los nombres de las columnas de tu tabla temporal:
SELECT name FROM  tempdb.sys.columns WHERE  object_id = Object_id('tempdb..#Tempo')

Comment: Funcioníó muy bien

Comment: Esposible realizar una suma de estas columnas? en otro campo

Comment: Seguramente si, ya es cuestión de que juegues con el query y lo modifiques según tus necesidades.

Comment: Hola, quisiera saer cómo podría sumar las columnas M2+M3+M4, ya que tengo que esta suma debe ser retrocediendo12 columnas a partir de la columna M14