# Suma de campos de tabla

Tags: sql-server

Hola tengo mi tablatemporal ##TempoResumen y quiero tener una columna QTR que sume los valores de acuerdo a otra tabla  DDD_PERIODO1 que tenga la marca x:

tabla ##TempoResumen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla DDD_PERIODO1
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que me sume en un campo QTR el valor de las columnas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con esta línea de comandos da un error, alguien que me pueda guiar:

```
DECLARE @s nvarchar(max)
SET @s = 'SELECT *, '
DECLARE @Calc nvarchar(max)=''

SELECT
    @Calc = @Calc + '[' + COLUMN_NAME + ']'
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    WHERE TABLE_NAME = '##TempoResumen' 
    AND COLUMN_NAME IN(SELECT Tipo FROM DDD_PERIODO1 WHERE Calculo = 'x')

SET @s = @s + @Calc + ' AS ''Qtr'''
SET @s = @s + ' FROM ##TempoResumen'

PRINT @s
EXEC(@s)
```

Comment: Hola Ronald, en que varía esta pregunta con respecto a la que hiciste hace unos días?: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/327649/consulta-con-campos-din%c3%a1micos, pareciera que es la misma a la que le has agregado el código de la respuesta. Vuelvo sugerirte que agregues las estructuras de las tablas y los ejemplos como texto y no como imagen ¿que problema tiene el código? Saludos.

Comment: Ahora necesito incorporar una columna Qtr que sume los nuevos campos de tabla2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu escenario:

```
CREATE TABLE DDD_PERIODO1
(TIPO       VARCHAR(100)
, FECHA_DATA VARCHAR(100)
, PERIODO    VARCHAR(100)
, CALCULO    VARCHAR(1)
);
GO
INSERT INTO DDD_PERIODO1 (TIPO, FECHA_DATA, PERIODO, CALCULO)
VALUES
('M24','Sep-19','Sep-2019',''),
('M23','Aug-19','Aug-2019',''),
('M22','Jul-19','Jul-2019',''),
('M21','Jun-19','Jun-2019',''),
('M20','May-19','May-2019',''),
('M19','Apr-19','Apr-2019',''),
('M18','Mar-19','Mar-2019','X'),
('M17','Feb-19','Feb-2019','X'),
('M16','Ene-19','Ene-2019','X'),
('M15','Dec-18','Dec-2018',''),
('M14','Nov-18','Nov-2018','');
GO
```

Ten en cuenta que los tipos de datos pueden diferir de los tuyos, ya que de la imagen sólo se pueden obtener conclusiones, a veces equivocadas.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ##tempoResumen; -- SOLO VALIDO A PARTIR DE 2016

create table ##tempoResumen
(pais          VARCHAR(100)
, Unidad        VARCHAR(2)
, linea         VARCHAR(100)
, brick         INT
, Representante VARCHAR(100)
, Cod_Mercado   INT
, Mercado       VARCHAR(100)
, Periodo       VARCHAR(6)
, Terrtarget    VARCHAR(1000)
, M16           FLOAT
, M17           FLOAT
, M18           FLOAT
);


INSERT INTO ##tempoResumen (PAIS, UNIDAD, LINEA, BRICK,
Representante, Cod_Mercado, Mercado, Periodo, Terrtarget,
M16,M17,M18)
VALUES
('COSTA RICA','RX','CARDIO',1001,'AGUIRRE',6,'PLAVIX','112019',125.8185,12.97098,22.05066,23.34776 
)


DECLARE @s nvarchar(max)

DECLARE @Calc nvarchar(max)=''

SELECT @CALC =@CALC + CONCAT(QUOTENAME(TIPO),'+') FROM DDD_PERIODO1 WHERE CALCULO = 'X'
SELECT @CALC = SUBSTRING(@Calc,1,LEN(@CALC)-1);

SET @S = N'SELECT *, SUM('+@CALC +') OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS QTR
FROM ##tempoResumen
';

EXEC sp_executeSql @s;
```

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta, es que no indicas si la suma es única para una fila, si tiene que ser para todos los registros, si tiene que ser particionada por algunos. Puede ser que tengas que quitar la clausula over y cambiarla por un group by. Pero para este escenario, esta puede ser una de las múltiples soluciones.

[image: Qtr 58.3694]